# jquery ajax sucess data access embedded objects

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

```
{ "id": "36", "title": "Dr","firstname": "Ian", "lastname": "Fletcher", "permissions": { "permissionlist": [{ "title": "Images", "accessid": "152"},{ "title": "Documents", "accessid": ""}] } }
```

I have an ajax callback with the above data and need some help in getting some of the data out.

I have managed to get the data out of the callback data e.g. id, title firstname, lastname, but am struggling to get the permissions out.

```
success: function(data) {

                    jQuery.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
                        $('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>').val(itemData.title);
                        $('#<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>').val(itemData.firstname);
                        $('#<%=txtSurname.ClientID %>').val(itemData.lastname);

                        jQuery.each(itemData.permissions, function(index, permissionData) {
                            alert(permissionData.title);
                        });
                    });
                }
```

I have attempted to use the each function using the permissions as the list but the alert is always displaying undefined.  Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itemData.permissions` is an object, not an array. The array is in the property `permissionlist`.

```
jQuery.each(itemData.permissions.permissionlist, function(index, permissionData) {
                            alert(permissionData.title);
                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the wrong property, inside permissions you still have a permissionList:

```
jQuery.each(itemData.permissions.permissionList, function(index, permissionData) {
  alert(permissionData.title);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`permissions` is an object that has a `permissionList` element that contains an array of objects.  You are not iterating over the array, but over the `permissionlist` object itself.  Use:

```
jQuery.each(itemData.permissions.permissionlist)
```

You could also use `permissionData[0].title`, but that only gets the *first* title.

I've seen a question like this asked enough times to create this: https://github.com/ajcrites/json-visualize/

You can see it used for this question here: http://jsfiddle.net/4cb2b/

Answer (score 2):

`data` is the object returned from the ajax call. Loop through the properties at each level and you will see the structure

```
function success(data) {
    // data
    jQuery.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
        alert('index=' + index + ', itemData=' + itemData);
    });
    // data.permissions
    jQuery.each(data.permissions, function (index, itemData) {
        alert('index=' + index + ', itemData=' + itemData);
    });
    // data.permissions.permissionlist
    jQuery.each(data.permissions.permissionlist, function (index, itemData) {
        alert('index=' + index + ', itemData=' + itemData);
    });
    // ...
}

success(data);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5DPZ/) for testing